# Validation rule to make WhoId required on Task

Tags: formula, administration, validation, validation-rule, configuration

I am trying to write validation rule on task to make WhoId as required field. Tried following as Error Condition formula :

```
ISBLANK(WhoId)
ISNULL((WhoId)
```

After little research found that WhoId is a polymorphic field and this field cannot be used in salesforce validation rule formula.

Are there any workarounds for this or am I missing anything here? (I want to avoid writing code for this unless it is the last option)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You appear to have an extra opening parenthesis. This `Validation Rule` saves for me:

```
ISBLANK(WhoId)
```

Whereas the formula you provided gives a syntax error:

> Error: Syntax error. Missing ')'

---

Here are some screenshots to prove it works in my org:

**Rule**

[image: Validation Rule Detail]

**Error**

[image: You must specify a WhoId]

---

PS - A word on [the post you refer to from which you interpreted you cannot reference `WhoId`](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/140284/2995). You cannot reach through that relationship to get fields off the `Who` parent, but you can reference the `WhoId` field itself.

**No Joy**

```
Who.Name
```

**Joy**

```
WhoId
```

Comment: It gets saved but is not working as expected.

Comment: @pmvsdt Hmm, it works perfectly for me. Did you make sure it's active?

Comment: I just rechecked and VR is active. when I edit an existing task associated to case, remove its WhoId (make the value of related contact null) and save, it is getting saved but as per this VR it shouldnt be saved.

Comment: Again, this is my entire rule and it blocks insert and update when `WhoId` is not populated. Maybe you have some logic filling it in. Are you sure the value is actually null after the save succeeds?

Comment: Keeping that VR active, now edit your task, populate a contact and save, I believe u will still see that VR error message..

Comment: It allows me to save when the lookup is populated, and blocks it when it's not. Sounds like exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52328/discussion-between-pmvsdt-and-adrian-larson).

Comment: There was some logic in my trigger that is overwriting VR formula evaluation. I didnt notice that. Thanks for your help ..